# MPMediaItem How do you play it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app I have a user select a song from the library and I receive that song as a MPMediaItem, what I am attempting to figure out is how to play the MediaItem in a separate audio player on the app so the user can control various things about the playback. I looked into some methods of how this is done but they all include having to export and convert the media item into a different audio format. Is it possible for what I am asking to be done?

Thanks again in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the class you'll want to look into is [`MPMusicPlaybackController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221).

First you obtain an instance via one of two class methods, `+applicationMusicPlayer` or `+iPodMusicPlayer`. Then you set up a playback queue with either an `MPMediaQuery` or an `MPMediaItemCollection`.

Comment: THanks, Would you know how to seek to a point in the song that a user specifies? And play from that certain point?

Comment: currentPlaybackTime
I looked into this property but I don't think it is editable if using from the iPod library.

Comment: There isn't an API that allows you to start playing a media item at an arbitrary point.

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to get around that?

Comment: I figured out a way, Use the AVPlayer instead of the MPMusicPlaybackController. Only available in the 4.0+

Answer (score 0):

MPMusicPlayerController enables you to play an MPMediaItem.  Check out the setQueueWithItemCollection method: [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)